# Laravel Eloquent query siblings in same table with eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, siblings

I have a parent table called `patients` which has a one-to-many relationship with a child table called `notes`. (i.e. One patient can have several notes). If given a note, I would like to find other notes for the same patient. Notes are related to patients by a fk called `patient_id`.

In SQL, I'd do this:

`SELECT * FROM notes WHERE patient_id={note.patient_id} AND id <> {note.id}`

In Eloquent, I have this:

```
class Note extends Model
{

    public function otherEncounterNotes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Note', 'patient_id', 'patient_id')->where('id', '<>',$this->id);
    }
...
```

In my database, the patient with id=1 has two notes with ids 1 and 2, so if I look for the siblings of note id 1, I should get note id 2.

When I use `find()`, it works as expected, but when I use `where()`, it returns the original note instead of the sibling. Any ideas?

```
>>> Note::find(1)->otherEncounterNotes->pluck('id')                                                                                                                                                                             
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#5542
     all: [
       2,
     ],
   }

>>> Note::where('id',1)->with('otherEncounterNotes')->pluck('id')                                                                                                                                                               
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#5526
     all: [
       1,
     ],
   }
```

Comment: `find(1)` is returning the Model from the database so when the relationship method is called, `otherEncounterNotes`, (`$this->id`) has a value since that method is being called directly on that instance and you are plucking from the collection returned ... the second one is plucking from the table directly [regardless of any relationship] (calling `with` to eager load the relationship has no effect on the base result)

Comment: @lagbox - is there any way to eager load with logic that involves the id?

Comment: no, because eager loading uses a new non existing model to get the builder from the relationship method, it doesn't make the call on a model retrieved from the database with attributes

Comment: The best I could do was `Note::where('id',1)->get(['id','patient_id'])->each->append('otherEncounterNotes')  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a `Note` id, you could obtain the results you want by using the relationship with the `Patient` model.

```php
$note_id = 1;

// "Pretty" syntax, but it's 3 queries
$sibling_notes = Note::find($note_id)                                      // Query 1
                      ->patient                                            // Query 2
                      ->notes()->where('id', '<>', $note_id)->pluck('id'); // Query 3
```

Or using a subquery

```php
$note_id = 1;

// A bit messier, 1 query + 1 subquery
$sibling_notes = Note::where('id', '<>', $note_id)
    ->where('patient_id', function ($subquery) use ($note_id) {
        $subquery->select('patient_id')->from('notes')->where('id', $note_id)->limit(1);
    })
    ->pluck('id');

// PHP >= 7.4
Note::where('id', '<>', $note_id)
    ->where('patient_id', fn($q) => $q->select('patient_id')->from('notes')->where('id', $note_id)->limit(1))
    ->pluck('id');
```

The later, you could turn into a query scope

```php
# Note model
public function scopeSiblingsOf($query, $note_id)
{
    return $query->where('id', '<>', $note_id)
                 ->where('patient_id', function ($subquery) use ($note_id) {
                     $subquery->select('patient_id')
                              ->from('notes')
                              ->where('id', $note_id)
                              ->limit(1);
                 });
}

# Usage
Note::siblingsOf(1)->pluck('id');
```